# how to get the day information out of a string

Tags: r, gsub

I have a date data which have different input format. I would like to keep only number for it. what should I do.

The data looks like this:
[image]

The codes are:

```
Days<-c("Day 1","Day 4","   Day_6", "Day7")

Sample.data <- data.frame(Days)
```

Basicly I want to get the number out of Days.  Was thinking use 'str_replace' or 'gsub' but don't know how to handle different pattern. Please give me as many methods as possible for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: [`Sample.data$Day <- gsub("\\D+", "", Sample.data$Days)`](https://ideone.com/dhm9oC)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> Sample.data$Day <- as.numeric(gsub('(.*)(\\d)', '\\2', Sample.data$Days))
> Sample.data
      Days Day
1    Day 1   1
2    Day 4   4
3    Day_6   6
4     Day7   7
>
```